# Generate LINQ to XML C# code, from an XML document?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

Does anybody know of a tool that will generate LINQ to XML code from a real XML document or fragment?  It's reverse-engineering the common scenario of generating XML.

For example, I want to provide an XML fragment as input like this

```
<root>
    <thing>value</thing>
</root>
```

and have it generate the equivalent C# LINQ to XML code snippet like so

```
var x = new XElement("root",
    new XElement("thing", new XText("value"));
    );
```

Although I'm looking for a quickie, I'm sure some enterprising individuals will tell me to roll my own and provide some awesome reference code.

Answer (score 6):

See [this](http://net2csgenxlinq.codeplex.com/) tool.

> the application supports :
>
> - XDocument
> - XDeclaration
> - XProcessingInstruction
> - XComment
> - XNamespace
> - XElement
> - XAttribute
> - generation of business objects
> - generation of code Linq To Xml (with variables, in method, extraction of
>     the code corresponding to the selected
>     nodes)
> - you can open a Xml file or directly copy to stick xml in the richtextbox
> - the editor allows to create Xml documents from scratch or to
>     add/modify existing Xml documents
> - the editor has several views which are synchronized (Text, treeview)
> - a help with the seizure (auto completion tags and attributes and
>     checking in the course of the good
>     formation of xml) for the text view,…
> - you can also post the data of the nodes selected in a datagridview
> - etc

Comment: I saw it was in French, tried Google translate, and then posted my question here. However if more than one of us has targeted it by Googling then maybe I should take a peek.

Comment: @John K Did You mean The Documentation was in French?
ITs Both in French and English

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be hard to do using T4 templates, or an XSL transform for that matter, but I don't know anyone who's done it.